# How to print out request to log

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to debug a Laravel web api. I am having trouble printing the request to log:

```
use Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ Log;
//...
  function text(Request $request) {
    Log::info(print_r($request, true));
    //...
  }
```

The preceding code prints over 10 MB to the log. The same line without the "true" parameter prints only the date and time and nothing else. var_dump prints the same. dd does not print anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
use Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ Log;
//...
  function text(Request $request) {
    Log::info($request);
    //...
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`$request` is a object, when u wanna debug, u just wanna show some info of it.

Such as:
your request data: `$request->input()` 
your upload file: `$request->allFiles();`

And u also can use `Log::error()` try make debug info clearer.